# Update Windows 8 Live Tile With Video

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, xaml, windows-runtime

I know it is possible to update a live tile in Windows 8 with image and text. But, I wanted to  update the tile with a video.

Is it possible? If a video cannot be sent directly, can we break the video into many images and then update?

Comment: I would try a .gif file, which can be a video, albeit a short one :)

Comment: you will not be able to cycle through many images. as Mayank said: Too much system resources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add video to the live tiles neither the gif images (you can add gif's but they won't work as intended). Adding video is not allowed since it'll consume lot's of system recourses in the background task. The purpose of live tile's are to show information not content itself so that user can just glance on it and take action if needed.